# How to loop through list of timestamps and find timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a list of timestamps and want to loop through them and see if the time-delta between each of them is greater than 4 hours here is some pseudo code I tried but I do not know the syntax in pandas:

```
timestamps = ["7/20/2020  12:38:39 AM", "7/20/2020  2:50:46 AM","7/25/2020  7:18:55 PM"]

for x in range(0,len(timestamps)-1):
    t1 = timestamps[x]
    t2 = time[timestamps[x+1]
    if (t2 - t1) >4 hours:
        print('Greater Than 4 hours!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use datetime module from datetime library:

```
import datetime as dt
timestamps = ["7/20/2020  12:38:39 AM", "7/20/2020  2:50:46 AM","7/25/2020  7:18:55 PM"]

for x in range(0,len(timestamps)-1):
    t1 = dt.datetime.strptime(timestamps[x], "%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p")
    t2 = dt.datetime.strptime(timestamps[x+1], "%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p")
    if (t2 - t1) > dt.timedelta(hours=4):
        print(x, 'Greater Than 4 hours!')
    else:
        print(x, 'Not Greater Than 4 hours!')
```

Alternately, you could also try using the below instead of timedelta:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

pd.to_datetime() is also an option but pandas being a heavy library, I would stay away from it unless already using it at other places in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this answers your question:

```
import pandas as pd
timestamps = ["7/20/2020  12:38:39 AM", "7/20/2020  2:50:46 AM","7/25/2020  7:18:55 PM"]
timestamps = pd.to_datetime(timestamps)

for i in range(0,len(timestamps)-1):
    t1 = timestamps[i]
    t2 = timestamps[i+1]
    diff = (t2 - t1).seconds / 3600
    if diff > 4:
        print('Greater Than 4 hours!')
```